# bitcoinjs-lib seems to skip a step in deriving addresses from a BIP 44 wallet

Tags: address, address-generation, bitcoinjs, bip44

[According to this wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses) to create a bitcoin address,

1) you have your public key of the properly derived path

2) Then SHA256 it

3) Then RIPEMD-160 it,

Add version byte at the front and boom blam you’re good.

But in [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/bip32.js#L11), they have this function getAddress which seems to skip step 2  and continue down the path ensuring Base58Checking

```
function getAddress (node) {
  return baddress.toBase58Check(bcrypto.hash160(node.publicKey), bitcoin.networks.bitcoin.pubKeyHash)
}
```

My question is, why is bitcoinjs-lib skipping step 1? Don’t you have to SHA256 the pub key again?

Derivation occurs pretty straightforwardly with `derivePath`

`var child1 = root.derivePath("m/44'/0'/0'/0/0")`

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/src/crypto.js `hash160(buffer)` _is_ `ripemd160(sha256(buffer))`

Comment: Yes, that is obvious. The step skipped is the extra SHA256

Comment: Ah I see, my bad. Leave a proper answer so I can give you credit